# Not able to produce action upon clicking the button

Tags: php, html, css, forms, tailwind-css

I am using the below code from `Tailblocks` [Link](https://tailblocks.cc/) under `CTA` section , upon clicking the button I am not able to get to new page. In the below code `form` tags are added by me. please guide how can I resolve it?

```
<form ction="index.php" method="post">

   <section class="text-gray-600 body-font">
      <div class="container px-5 py-24 mx-auto flex flex-wrap items-center">
        <div class="lg:w-3/5 md:w-1/2 md:pr-16 lg:pr-0 pr-0">
          <h1 class="title-font font-medium text-3xl text-gray-900">Slow-carb next level shoindcgoitch ethical authentic, poko scenester</h1>
          <p class="leading-relaxed mt-4">Poke slow-carb mixtape knausgaard, typewriter street art gentrify hammock starladder roathse. Craies vegan tousled etsy austin.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="lg:w-2/6 md:w-1/2 bg-gray-100 rounded-lg p-8 flex flex-col md:ml-auto w-full mt-10 md:mt-0">
          <h2 class="text-gray-900 text-lg font-medium title-font mb-5">Sign Up</h2>
          <div class="relative mb-4">
            <label for="full-name" class="leading-7 text-sm text-gray-600">Full Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="full-name" name="full-name" class="w-full bg-white rounded border border-gray-300 focus:border-indigo-500 focus:ring-2 focus:ring-indigo-200 text-base outline-none text-gray-700 py-1 px-3 leading-8 transition-colors duration-200 ease-in-out">
          </div>
          <div class="relative mb-4">
            <label for="email" class="leading-7 text-sm text-gray-600">Email</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="w-full bg-white rounded border border-gray-300 focus:border-indigo-500 focus:ring-2 focus:ring-indigo-200 text-base outline-none text-gray-700 py-1 px-3 leading-8 transition-colors duration-200 ease-in-out">
          </div>
          <button class="text-white bg-indigo-500 border-0 py-2 px-8 focus:outline-none hover:bg-indigo-600 rounded text-lg">Button</button>
          <p class="text-xs text-gray-500 mt-3">Literally you probably haven't heard of them jean shorts.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You form action attribute is having a typo.

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
```

Also, instead of button you need to select the input type as submit.

```
<input type='submit' class="text-white bg-indigo-500 border-0 py-2 px-8 focus:outline-none hover:bg-indigo-600 rounded text-lg" value="Button">
```

else add some JS to submit the form

```
  <script>
    var forms = document.getElementsByTagName('form');
    for(var i = 0; i < forms.length; i += 1) {
        forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }, true);
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo error in action attribute in your form tag.

```html
<form action="index.php" method="post">
```

Also you don't add the type attribute to your button tag.

```html
 <button type="submit" class="text-white bg-indigo-500 border-0 py-2 px-8 focus:outline-none hover:bg-indigo-600 rounded text-lg">Button</button>
```

I hope this will fix your problem.